# How to skip a column check with condition using Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

In Django ORM how can we skip checking for a column if a condition is true? And how to check for that column with a specific value if the condition is false.

For example, how can we achieve following mysql condition with Django ORM?

```
IF(product.display_stock > 0,'0',product.hide) = 0
```

The need here is, if product's `display_stock is > 0`, then I don't care what the value of `hide` column contains. If `display_stock = 0`, then I need to confirm `hide = 0`.

Any help form Django ORM experts is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the `QuerySet` that you return from the ORM.

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/

```
Product.objects.extra(select={'in_stock': "display_stock > 0"}).all()
```

Or

```
Product.objects.filter(display_stock=0).all()
```